# apache mod rewrite too many redirects

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect all requests for my default language (nl) to /nl..... (without showing the redirect to the user). So example.com should redirect to example.com/nl without visibly altering the url in the browser. Here is what I tried:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/nl.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$  nl$1 [R,L]
```

The redirect is visible to the user (/nl/index.php) and in addition it results in a 'too many redirect'.

If I try [P,L] I get: no permission to access '\' on this server.

What is the correct way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's shouldn't be an `[R]` after the RewriteRule as this tells Apache to send a 302 redirect rather than internally rewriting the URL.

The second part of the RewriteRule should start with a slash unless this is in a Directory context (such as in a `.htaccess` file or a `<Directory >` block).  Without the slash, you are rewriting the URL to something like `http://example.comnl/index.php` rather than `http://example.com/nl/index.php`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/nl.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /nl$1 [L]
```

Comment: I then get: Internal Server Error and in my log: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.
r->uri = /index.php
redirected from r->uri = /index.php
redirected from r->uri = /index.php
...
redirected from r->uri = /

Comment: Is this the only rewrite rule you have in your configuration?  The above rules and even your original rules are not able to cause that redirect to happen.

Comment: there was another rule which caused the trouble, it works now, thanks!